# Python: how can I change line 18 to only except an integer so it can pass through the sum command. thanks

Tags: python, while-loop, sum, integer, range

How can I only except an integer so it can pass through the sum command? I need to add the list together then multiply by `.1`.

```
bottles = [] 

while True:

    option = input('would you like to contiune? yes or quit ')

    if option == 'yes':
     
      num = [(input("enter an int") for _ in range(7))]
      print (f'payout: {sum(bottles*.10)}$')
      break
    if option == 'quit':
      quit("you get no payment")
```

Comment: The `input` function returns a string. You need to convert it to a number before passing it to `sum`. `bottles = [float(input("enter a number: ")) for _ in range(7)]`

Comment: python input integer only:  num = int(input("Enter an integer number: ")) are you looking for it ?

Comment: You add a pair of parentheses that should not appear `[*(*input(...) for ...*)*]`, which makes the list of string become a list of generator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like how fpf3 sakdy, `input()` returns what user typed in the terminal, a string. Thankfully, Python is not JavaScript, and in order to use the extracted value in arithmetic operations, you need to first convert it into an integer with its constructor: `int()`. You can also cast data to different types with datatype constructors as well, and you can convert a number back to a string with `str()`. Pay attention that this is important if you print multiple pieces of data in one call: if you will want to print the `sum` result with some text, you will need to convert everything into text.

Also, a note from me:

1. You don't need a `break` keyword to exit branches, unless this code is inside a loop, then it's fine.
2. If you only have two branches, you can use `else` to describe the other one. Now if you need the `option` to be precisely "quit", you may do so, however than it makes sense to anticipate other edge cases if user types anything else. Consider using `assert` function or making another branch explaining the invalid input.
3. This structure of two ifs is fine, but in the future when you have a chain of branches, use `elif` or `match`s.

Comment: bottles = [] 

while True:

  
    option = (input('would you like to contiune? yes or quit '))

    if option == 'yes':
      bottles = [float(input("enter a number: ")) for _ in range(7)]
    #i can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'(would you have any suggestion on how to fix this ? Im greatful for your help!
    pay=(float(sum(bottles*.1)))
    print (pay)

    if option == 'quit':
      quit("you get no payment")

Comment: What is the `bottles` list for? I see you convert to the input into the float type, and it seems to me you want to repeat it 7 types. This syntax is illegal then, use an ordinary loop here. You may also look at [when to use loop comprehensions. ](https://realpython.com/list-comprehension-python/)